# Deploy Artifact to Nexus from Eclipse

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, m2eclipse, m2e

Is it possible to run mvn deploy from Eclipse using M2E?  I have the distributionManagement section in my pom.xml and the server configured in my settings.xml, but I can't for the life of me see where I can fire of that specific goal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the distributionManagement section of your pom is setup properly and pointing to your Nexus, you just need to run the Maven

```
deploy
```

goal.

Assuming that you installed the m2eclipse Maven Eclipse plugin, right click your project or your pom, Run As>Maven build and enter the goal "deploy" on the goals line.

If you did not install a Maven Eclipse plugin, add an External Tools configuration pointing to your Maven install for its "Location" and your project dir for its "working directory", with "deploy" as its argument.

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping I would be able to accomplish it with as little (read: no) client config as possible.  Looks like I may have to create an ant task for it.

Comment: This works for me on single maven projects, but when I have multi maven projects with parent pom with distributionManagement I get this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15493954/error-during-deployment-of-artifacts-to-nexus-from-eclipse. You know what I'm doing wrong?