# Error during deployment of artifacts to Nexus from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, nexus, artifacts

Installed Nexus on our server and set up a snapshot and a releases repositories.

Altered my pom.xml file of the top project in my sub-module maven project, added these lines:

```
  <distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>Snapshots</id>
        <url>http://maven:8081/nexus/content/repositories/Snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
        <id>Releases</id>
        <url>http://maven:8081/nexus/content/repositories/Releases</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

I've added a settings.xml to .m2 directory with the following contents:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <!--
  <localRepository/>
  <interactiveMode/>
  <usePluginRegistry/>
  <offline/>
  <pluginGroups/>
  -->
  <servers>

    <server>
      <id>Snapshots</id>
      <username>user</username>
      <password>pass</password>

      <privateKey>${user.home}/.ssh/id_dsa</privateKey>
      <passphrase>some_passphrase</passphrase>

      <filePermissions>664</filePermissions>
      <directoryPermissions>775</directoryPermissions>
      <configuration></configuration>

    </server>

  </servers>
  <!--
  <mirrors/>
  <proxies/>
  <profiles/>
  <activeProfiles/>
  -->
</settings>
```

When I run maven with deploy goal from eclipse on my top project, maven starts to build and syncing (uploading) to the snapshots repo. The top project gets uploaded but after the first sub module is built and started to sync I keep getting:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project <my sub module project>: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact <group id>:<artifact id>:xml:0.0.1-20130318.160312-21 from/to Snapshots (http://maven:8081/nexus/content/repositories/Snapshots): Remotely Closed [id: 0x017ae341, /192.168.10.237:58758 :> maven/192.168.10.36:8081]
```

The weird thing is that if I browse my repo from Nexus interface the sub project is there with xml's and jar's etc. Problem though is that because of the error maven stops and all my other sub projects isn't deployed.

Anyone know how to resolve this?

**UPDATE:**
If I create a single maven project with distributionManagement-tag I can deploy without problems to Nexus. But when having multi maven project I get the error. I tried to add distributionManagement to child-pom to but I get the same error.

How should the poms look like en deploying to a repository regarding distributionManagement tag ?

Comment: "Remotely Closed"... take a look at Nexus logs may help. Or something with a proxy somewhere on the road to your Nexus repository.

Comment: read this http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Comment: When you say proxy do you mean a maven proxy or a proxy on tcp/ip level? I don't think It can be a proxy problem, my artifacts ends up on the maven server. And if I type in wrong credentials in settings.xml I get a authorization error.

Comment: I mean a proxy at TCP level (not the repository manager). Anyway, even if you are successfully uploading one artifact, it don't means that your proxy not implied in this issue. It is still possible that (because of some rules in your proxy) it close abruptly the connection.

Comment: From what I know we don't have any proxy on our client computers. The maven server and my client is located on the same network even.

Comment: If one read here http://kevinlocke.name/bits/2012/10/03/ssl-certificate-verification-in-dispatch-and-asynchttpclient/ there seems to be some bug in asynchttpclient which is part of the stacktrace that indicates some ssl problem but I don't use ssl when connecting to nexus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some hours investigation I found my problem.
I have a section in my parent pom.xml that adds a features.xml to parent repo.

```
<build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>${maven-resources-plugin.version}</version>
              <executions>
                 <execution>
                    <id>filter</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                 </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${build-helper-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-artifacts</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifacts>
                                <artifact>
                                    <file>target/classes/features.xml</file>
                                    <type>xml</type>
                                </artifact>
                            </artifacts>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
         </plugins>
   </build>
```

This one caused the "Remotely closed" issue.